# Как сделать чтобы хинты (всплывающие подсказки) показывались всегда а не только при наведении мышкой на Яндекс карте

Tags: яндекс-карты

Реализовал вывод меток на карте следующим образом:

```
`Collection.add(new ymaps.Placemark(point, {
                    hintContent: name,
                    balloonContent:baloon_html,
                    city_id:city_id,
                }, 
                {
                //    iconLayout: 'default#image',
                    // Своё изображение иконки метки.
                    openBalloonOnClick: true,
                    hideIconOnBalloonOpen: false,
                    balloonMaxWidth:800,

                // Размеры метки.
                }
            ));
        }
    }
    myMap.geoObjects.add(Collection);`
```

Нужно чтобы у меток были подписаны города. Решил сделать через всплывающие подсказки - сделать их видимыми. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это реализовать.

Comment: Вам лучше сделать свой макет подписей, потому что это уже не совсем хинт. Или использовать макет метки default#imageWithContent

Comment: В коде не видно, что ваши метки имеют кастомное изображение. Если вы готовы использовать стандартные метки, то задача очень просто решается такой меткой https://jsfiddle.net/ok7aLfs0/